# Printing on android tablets with window.print

Tags: javascript, android

I have a web app where i need the client to print on the local printer of android tablets.
Using the window.print() works fine.

```
function printme(){
window.print();}
```

However if i add window.open() and execute the window.print()

```
function printme(){
var divToPrint=document.getElementById("receipt");
newWin= window.open("");
newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
newWin.print();
newWin.close();}
```

Nothing gets printed on android but using a windows desktop it works fine.

Problem is replicated on FF and chrome

Any reason why?
This works fine on desktops.

Comment: "Using the window.print() works fine" -- that will depend entirely on the Web browser. "Any reason why?" -- you presumably hit some limitation in that Web browser. Without a [mcve] and details of the specific browser that you are testing, it will be difficult for anyone to help you. "This works fine on desktops" -- that will depend entirely on the Web browser, though I agree that it is more likely to be reliable there.

Comment: Edited. The problem on android with FF and chrome